# How to insert record into table result of other Select Query?

Tags: sql, database

My requirement is to insert record from selected query result in to new table.

My query is

```
SELECT        
   a.Section_name, b.sectionname, a.SubQno, b.Qno, a.ans, b.Answ, 
   a.Exame_id, b.Exame_id AS Expr1, b.User_id, b.Start_time, b.End_time
FROM Question AS a
INNER JOIN Solve_Student_question AS b ON a.SubQno = b.Qno AND a.Section_name = b.sectionname
WHERE (b.User_id = 'gopal ram51765078')
```

Now this query result stored in to `Temp` table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Insert Into ... Select` idiom like so:

```
INSERT INTO TempTable
(...) --Columns
SELECT        
a.Section_name, b.sectionname, a.SubQno, b.Qno, a.ans, b.Answ, a.Exame_id, b.Exame_id AS Expr1, b.User_id, b.Start_time, b.End_time
FROM Question AS a INNER JOIN
Solve_Student_question AS b ON a.SubQno = b.Qno AND a.Section_name = b.sectionname
WHERE (b.User_id = 'gopal ram51765078')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into [temptablename] (comma-separated list of column names) 
   (your Select Query Here)
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can use Cursor also for this case

```
declare
cursor C is
select a.Section_name, b.sectionname, a.SubQno, b.Qno, a.ans, 
b.Answ, a.Exame_id,    b.Exame_id AS Expr1, b.User_id, b.Start_time, b.End_time
FROM Question AS a INNER JOIN
Solve_Student_question AS b ON a.SubQno = b.Qno AND a.Section_name = b.sectionname
WHERE (b.User_id = 'gopal ram51765078');
begin
for i in C
insert into tablename(Column1,Column2,Column3)
        values(i.column1,i.Column2,i.Column3);
end loop;
Exit when last.record = 'TRUE';
end;
```

`

`

Comment: You *can* - but you should **avoid** cursors as much as you can. And here, for inserting a set of rows into a table, a cursor is a **really really BAD** choice! Don't do this!

Comment: Kindly explain why should we avoid cursors? Basically am a Forms developer i have done lot of inserting process like this only in Form level.please tell me it is wright or wrong?

Comment: Cursors are terribly slow, they eat up a lot of resources - and they offer no real benefit. SQL is a **set-based** system - you should avoid using **RBAR** (row-by-agonizing-row) processing in SQL, it's a bad fit, it's slow and messy, it uses unnecessarily many CPU cycles - just avoid it!